# Understanding button/mouse listener in Netbeans GUI generated code

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, mouselistener

can any tell me what this part of code is doing?

```
 jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() 
                           {
                 public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
                                 {
                     jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
                 }
                   });
```

why are there methods in the parameter for the method addMouseListener? can some one explain in details? im using netbeans and this is code generated.

Comment: It's an anonymous class.

Comment: `jButton1.addMouseListener`  Don't add a mouse listener to a button.  Use an `ActionListener`!  The action listener will respond to mouse **and** key board.  As a further tip:  Avoid GUI builders until you understand the components, listeners and layouts, or nonsense like this will result (where it produces poor code that you don't understand).

Comment: Wishing @AndrewThompson's comment were an answer as it is so far the only worthy answer to the question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I wish the question were closer to one where that could be entered as an answer.  Unfortunately use of an `ActionListener` would result in pretty much the same question, so it seems a peripheral matter as to whether the question is about `MouseListener` or `ActionListener`.  I do hope though, that expanding the tags will lead to better answers focused on action listener.  I don't have time ATM..

Answer (score 0):

It's an anonymous MouseAdapter, meaning it calls a new class instance without a variable/assignment. The code itself is calling a new custom event handling method `jButton1MouseClicked()`, which is what netbeans generates for you so that you can add in your own handling for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't add a mouse listener to a button. Well, I use this method to get the position of X and Y mouse click in my GUI using NetBeans.

Right-click the swing container: Choose Events: choose Mouse: choose MouseClicked. Add the following piece of code; (of course my text fields have the variable names tfMouseX and tfMouseY).

```
tfMouseX.setText(evt.getX() + "");
tfMouseY.setText(evt.getY() + "");
```